# selecting a tag value in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to convert a xml file to CSV and want to select some value from a tag which is already exist with the same name:

**XML file content sample:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <PayrunDetails>
        <PayrunNumber>000777</PayrunNumber>
    </PayrunDetails>
    <PayLocation>
        <LocationCode>ACT</LocationCode>
        <LocationDescription>ACT</LocationDescription>
        <CompanyDetails>
            <CName>APPLE Limited</CName>
            <Payslip>
                <StaffNumber>12345</StaffNumber>
                <PayDetails>
                    <AmountGross>9999</AmountGross>
                    <ComponentDetails>
                        <ComponentType ID="SALARY">
                            <Amount>1999</Amount>
                            <YTDAmount>10616</YTDAmount>
                        </ComponentType>
                    </ComponentDetails>
                    <ComponentDetails>
                        <ComponentType ID="TAX">
                            <Amount>7305</Amount>
                            <YTDAmount>76703</YTDAmount>
                        </ComponentType>
                    </ComponentDetails>
                </PayDetails>
            </Payslip>
        </CompanyDetails>
    </PayLocation>
</root>
```

In the above XML file you can see ComponentType having a ID 'SALARY' so I am checking it using a if condition but at the time of selection of 'Amount' it is selecting value from the ComponentType ID 'SALARY' as well as from 'TAX'.

**My XSL file :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:text> Amount &#xA;</xsl:text>
<xsl:for-each select="root">
    <xsl:for-each select="//Payslip">

    <xsl:if test="PayDetails/ComponentDetails/ComponentType/@ID='SALARY'">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="PayDetails/ComponentDetails/ComponentType/Amount"/>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template> 
<xsl:template match="*[contains(., ',')]">
<xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="." />
<xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the above xsl code I am using 'if' condition for checking the ComponentType='SALARY' and if it matches with the tag name then it will select the value from its subtag 'salary, but I fail to select only salary tag for the ComponentType='SALARY. It is selecting all the values exist with the name 'salary' in the XML file.
Please help me out of the problem, and tell me how to select specific tag in xsl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if condition is essentially say "If there are ComponentTypes with an ID of salary, then select all ComponentTypes. The `xsl:apply-templates` is a totally different statement to the `xsl:if`.

What you need to do is replace the `xsl:if` and `xsl:apply-templates` with a single `xsl:apply-templates` like so:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="PayDetails/ComponentDetails/ComponentType[@ID='SALARY']/Amount"/>
```

The square brackets in this case represent a condition that has to be tested for the node to be selected.

Comment: you are god of xsl TimC ;)

Comment: No. That would be [Michael Kay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415448/michael-kay)

Comment: One more issue, if in my xml file <ComponentType ID="SALARY">
                            <Amount>1999</Amount>
                        </ComponentType> is repeated two or more times 
 then how do I distinguish them??

Comment: or have I need to introduce a new tag to separate it??

Comment: Please don't ask supplementary questions in comments, unless it's simply a request to clarify the answer to your original question. Raise a new question.

Comment: Ok Sir Michael Kay